# I can not see the table in the object overview in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I found and opened a MS Access project but I don't get how the user can a table which doesn't shows in the table overview. Is it the case when you are creating  a make table query?

Thx in advance!

[image: use] [image]

Comment: Is it possible, that the mentioned table `IQ` isn't a table, but a query? Also it maybe could be that your database objects window (on the left side) is in a custom view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This likely is a query containing a subquery in the `FROM` clause. These can't be properly represented in design view. Use SQL view instead.

The subquery just exists inside the queries SQL, it's not a distinct object.

A simple query using a subquery to reproduce the issue:

```
SELECT *
FROM
   (SELECT * FROM Werk) NonExistentTable
```

When representing this query in design view, it'll show like it's querying from NonExistentTable, but it's really querying from Werk.

In your case, however, it'll probably be a more complicated underlying query.

Alternatively, one can define hidden temporary tables in Access that are not revealed, even when showing hidden objects and system objects, but those are rarely used.